# how can i get open street map addon for my blendet

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor, camera, compositing-nodes

I want to work on a city, this why I need to work on open street map, and I will need addon to import open street map. Please, If you are the one that God will use as my Angel(Helper), zip it to mightyaraba@gmail.com . you are blessed, Thank you in  advance.

Comment: try to follow instructions here https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/wiki/Import-OpenStreetMap-(.osm)

Comment: I have tried the link, when I wanted to download the add-on this is the code I saw--- # This is the release version of the plugin file io_import_scene_osm_dev.py
# If you would like to make edits, make them in the file io_import_scene_osm_dev.py and the other related modules
# To create the release version of io_import_scene_osm_dev.py, execute:
# python plugin_builder.py io_import_scene_osm_dev.py
bl_infoordm

Comment: I tried to python the code and execute it but nothing change.

Comment: As the page says you should 1) save that python code on your pc, on your desktop 2) use the button in blender preferences > addons to import addon from file, and import the file you saved before. 3) Then activate the new imported addon, 4) using file > import > imports .osm files (these are xml files exported from the open street map site).I tried before commenting, and it works. It's not difficult, but if you still need detailed steps, I'll add an answer.